# Servlet Filter not working

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to implement a servlet filter to adjust autharization in a web app. However filter is not invoked and I can't find why.

This is my filter implementation:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter{

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    LoginBean session = (LoginBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("LoginBean");
    String url = req.getRequestURI();

    if(session == null || !session.isLogged) {
        if(!(url.indexOf("/home/index.xhtml") >= 0)){
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/home/index.xhtml");          
        }
        else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        if(session.role == 1) {
            if(url.indexOf("/admin/*") >= 0 || url.indexOf("/home/index.xhtml") >=0){
            resp.sendRedirect("/user/index.xhtml");
            } else if (url.indexOf("/home/logout.xhtml") >= 0){
                req.getSession().removeAttribute("LoginBean");
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/home/index.xhtml");
            }
            else{
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            if(url.indexOf("/user/*") >= 0  || url.indexOf("/home/index.xhtml") >=0){
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/admin/index.xhtml");
                } else if (url.indexOf("/home/logout.xhtml") >= 0){
                    req.getSession().removeAttribute("LoginBean");
                    resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/home/index.xhtml");
                }
                else{
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
        }}}
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}   
}
```

Also, here is the filter mapping:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.ibm.club.data.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>LogginFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Filter seems only valid for /user/ URL-Pattern

Comment: filter-name values do not match between filter definition and filter mapping in web.xml. LoggingFilter vs LogginFilter...

Comment: @Ben that was something I tried to fix the error, I reverted it back but seems it stayed the same way in my post

Comment: @tt_emrah thanks, it seems i made a typo there

Comment: now my filter works but redirects to home page whatever I do

Comment: see/debug your code. you are calling **resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/home/index.xhtml");** which may your problem.

Comment: it seems my LoginBean session returns as null, now trying to find out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things and debugging I finally found out why my servlet filter does not work properly. First of all, as @Ben mentioned,  in web.xml file should be "/*" instead of "/user/*". Another error was as @tt_emrah stated the filter-name values did not match in web.xml. The main error was due to my misinterpretation of function ".indexOf()". Instead of using url.indexOf("/admin/*"), I should have used url.indexOf("/admin"). Thanks everyone for helping me out.